# Do I need to include <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" /> in Manifest when I use Google Play Billing Library version 5?

Tags: android, google-play

I was told that I should to include `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />` in Manifest File when I use Google Play Billing Library version 5 when I browse the [sample](https://github.com/wdtheprovider/in-app-purchases-subscription) project.

But in  the official sample project [Trivial Drive (Kotlin)](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/tree/master/TrivialDriveKotlin) which supports Google Play Billing Library version 4, I found `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />` isn't inculded  in Manifest File.

Do I need to inculdue `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />` in Manifest File when I use Google Play Billing Library version 5 ?

Answer (score 0):

Hay, accordind to [this](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin/issues/426) thers still an issue with version 5.
The pass around it is:

1. Open your AndroidManifest.xml
2. Add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` within `<manifest ......>`
3. After the last `<uses-permission ... />` add a new line with `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" tools:node="remove" />`
4. Rebuild and distribute your app

Hope it helps you.